# Operator overloading in an abstract class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, abstract-class

I don't know how to properly describe my problem, so I will show you:

**Main.cpp**

```
#include"stdafx.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char count = 'y';
    char del = 'y';
    char doi = 'l';
    length trl;
    angle krl;
    Sum *d2, *d3, *a;
    coordinates * ob = &trl;
    coordinates * bb = &krl;
    while (cont = 'y') {
        cout << "what program should do:" << endl;
        cout << "write c if you want find angle between two vectors " << endl;
        cout << "write l if you want find length between two points" << endl;
        cout << "write s if you want find two vectors sum" << endl;
        cin >> veiks;
        if (doi == 'l') { ob->action(); ob->Output(); }
        else if (doi == 'c') { bb->action(); bb->Output(); }
        else if (doi == 's') { a->action(); d3 = d2 + a; d3->Output(); }
        else cout << "No action isn't selected" << endl;
        cout << "If you want repeat program write: y, if you want end work press any key    "; cin >> count;
        if (count != 'y')
            break;
        cout << "Do you want to clean-up screen?   "; cin >> del;
        if (del == 'y') system("CLS");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In section `d3 = d2 + a` at `a` shows error:

```
expression must have integral or unscoped enum type
```

Any ideas how to solve it?

**.h** file

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;

class Sum: public coordinates {

public:
    void Output();
    void action();

    Sum operator+(Sum &d2) {
        Sum temp;
        temp.rdcoord = rdcoord + d2.rdcoord;
        temp.thcoord = thcoord + d2.thcoord;


        return temp;
    }
};
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to add 2 pointers together. You can do limited arithmetic with pointers, but adding addresses... Not a good idea.

Comment: But how? I am not a good programmer

Comment: Wish I could help, but I'm kind of puzzled at your intent here. What is that line supposed to do? Someone may be able to suggest an alternative.

Comment: @PovilasAdomaitis are you trying to add 2 pointers together, or is the intent  to call the `operator+` overload you've defined?

Comment: In which line i want to add 2 pointers? I do not get it the pointers essence

Comment: Try removing the pointers and trying again, you don't need them here.

Comment: If i remove pointer, i get other error: "expression must have pointer type"

Comment: I suspect what you mean to do is add `a` to `d2` to get `d3`.  But in addition to the syntax problem, you have that none of these have been allocated.  If so, here's your fix:  `Suma d2, d3, a;`.  ...If this isn't it, please try commenting your program ... and cut and paste it directly from your code.  I see other errors you'd have encountered if this were your code (like spelling `Sum` as `Suma` sometimes).

Comment: do me a favor and upload a copy on [pastebin](http://www.pastebin.com) and comment each line w/ what you intend to do there.  From there, we can help you understand what went wrong

Comment: sorry. i try to translate from my language to english and i didn't fully translated

Comment: i solve it. i have to remove pointers. and make change in _a->action(); d3 = d2 + a; d3->Output();_ to **a.action(); d3 = d2 + a; d3.Output();**

Comment: @pov post that as an answer, not a comment!